# jquery document body one click event

Tags: jquery, events

Could somebody help me with this? :

I have a button that when clicked it shows a certain div. This div has several descendants. Now, what I want is that when I click somewhere else in the document, **but not in any of those descendants** that this div disappears.
what I thought was to use the not selector like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").show();
    $(document.body).not($("#mydiv").children()).one('click',function(e) {
        $("#mydiv").hide(); 
    });
        return false;   
});
```

but this is not working! Any idea why? thanks

Comment: Also, my question: I understand that one binds the event only once to all the matching elements. So if the user clicks "element a" outside the div (the div is now hidden) and then clicks "element b" outside the div, this event would fire again for "element b" ??

Answer (score 16, accepted):

How about checking the click event to see what was clicked? Specifically look at the `event.target`.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);

  if (!target.attr('id').match(/^mydiv/) && target.parents('#mydiv').length == 0) {
    $('#mydiv').hide();
  }
});
```

I have used this code before to close an open window when someone clicks anywhere but the window.

Comment: I don't wanna exclude only that id but also all the descendants of that element

Comment: Try the updated code, it should check that the target doesn't have any parents whose id is "mydiv".

Answer (score 5):

Use closest to check if the target is a descendant of `mydiv`.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#mydiv").show();
    $(document.body).click(function() {
        if ($(event.target).closest("#mydiv").length == 0)
            $("#mydiv").hide();     
    });
    return false;   
});
```

You can't use `one()` because the event would get removed if you click inside `mydiv`. You'll have to do some custom event unbinding if you want to remove it.

Comment: that does not work because the $(this) object is the document.body

Comment: Sorry. Forgot you had to use target. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with what you are passing in to the `.not()` to exclude

```
.not($("#mydiv").children())
```

At the moment you are passing a jQuery object in, but [from the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not#expr), what is passed into `.not()` should be either a string selector, a DOM element or an array of DOM elements. Therefore simply converting the jQuery object to an array of elements should work

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var myDiv = $("#mydiv").show();
    $(document.body).not(myDiv.children().get()).one('click',function(e) {
        myDiv.hide();     
    });
        return false;   
});
```

Comment: well, I have learned something new now, but still doesnt solve my problem. Thanks anyway