# when i click on div area, div should be disappear, and when i click on anywhere in the page div should appear

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
   alert("22");

   $('.clickme').click(function(){
       $('#popup_box1').toggleClass('opacityfilter');
 });
 });
</script>

<style>
.opacityfilter {
    _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */       
    height:350px;       
    width:600px;       
    background:#FFFFFF;       
    left: 33%;/*300px;     */
    right:30%;
    text-align:left;
    top: 150px;     
    z-index:100;      
    margin-left: 0;           
    padding:15px;       
    font-size:15px;       
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;     
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 15px #ff0000;     
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px lightblue;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); /* Color white with alpha 0.9*/
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); opacity:0.5;
    }
</style>
<a class="clickme">
 <div id="popup_box1" class="opacityfilter"> 
 click here</div>
 </a>
```

please tell me, how div tag will appear when click on anywhere on the page, but if user click on div area then div should be disappear but content of that div should be visible to user

Answer (score 3):

You have to attach the `click` handler for the `document` and you have to make decision depends on `e.target`.

Try,

```
  $(document).click(function(e){   
       if($(e.target).is('.clickme')){
           // show the div
       }
       else {
           //hide the div
       }
  });
```

As pavlo said you can make this as a one liner code like,

```
  $(document).click(function(e){   
       $('#YourDiv').toggle($(e.target).is('.clickme'));
  });
```

Comment: You probably missed `if` statement

Comment: Is this not a bit of an overhead attaching a click handler and check on document. Would probably better to bind a click even only once the initial click has been done and then unbind it once its fired.

Comment: What about this approach: `$('#content').toggle(!$(e.target).is('#content'));` In your case when click on the document (not on the button) the button will be hidden and how to show back the button?

Comment: @Pavlo ah.. what a typo that was. And your new code will be fine!\

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(document).click(function(event) {
      var target = $(event.target);
      if (target.attr('id').match(/^mydiv/)){
            //on div
      }else{
            //on body
      }
});
```

Refrence  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925097/jquery-document-body-one-click-event).